# ¿Como puedo actualizar multiples valores de una table con el mismo ID?

Tags: php, php8

Hola que tal buen día grupo tengo un problema con mi código, no puedo actualizar los datos de una tabla que contienen el mismo id, son 7 valores los que hay que actualizar los cuales cada valor es un día de la semana, cuando actualizo datos, solo cambia los datos del ultimo input es decir del domingo o en este caso del código de a continuación seria martes, de Lunes o y de los demás días no cambia valores.

Este es el html de los inputs

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 1 ; $i++) { ?>

<button type="button" class="boton_diasvisit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Lunes</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse collapsevisit">
        ¿Día disponible para visita?
        <select id="Lunes" name="visitday[]" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:5px;border:1px solid #1f6f8b;">
        <option selected >Selecciona una opción</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Sí">Sí</option>
        </select>
        <div id="pickdate">
            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="text" value="Lunes" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" name="dayvisit[]">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Inicio</label>
                <input type="time" id="appt" name="horainicio[]" class="form-control" style="border:1px solid #1f6f8b;" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Termino</label>
                <input type="time" id="appt" name="horafin[]" class="form-control" style="border:1px solid #1f6f8b;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="boton_diasvisit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Martes</button>
<div id="demo2" class="collapse collapsevisit">
        ¿Día disponible para visita?
        <select id="Martes" name="visitday[]" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:5px;border:1px solid #1f6f8b;">
        <option selected >Selecciona una opción</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Sí">Sí</option>
        </select>
        <div id="pickdateM">
            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="text" value="Martes" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" name="dayvisit[]">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Inicio</label>
                <input type="time" id="appt" name="horainicio[]" class="form-control" style="border:1px solid #1f6f8b;" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Termino</label>
                <input type="time" id="appt" name="horafin[]" class="form-control" style="border:1px solid #1f6f8b;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

y asi sucesivamente son 7 inputs para todos los dias de la semana, pero no consigo que actualice todos lo valores con los datos que son

Este es mi codigo PHP

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($visit_day); $i++){
          $cadena ="UPDATE visit_days SET dia = '{$visit_day[$i]}', visit = '{$dia[$i]}', hora_inicio = '{$horai[$i]}', hora_termino = '{$horaf[$i]}' WHERE id = '{$_GET['id']}' LIMIT 1";
      }

      if (mysqli_query($db, $cadena)) {
          header("Location: ".$web_settings['weblink']."mispropiedades.php");
       }
       else{
          echo 'No';
       }
```

Aqui una imagen de mi bd, la tabla se llama visit_days.

[image: Imagen de la BD]

Espero me puedan ayudar porfavooor! D:

Answer (score 0):

Realmente te los está actualizando todos pero, con el siguiente, se sobreescribe el anterior, por eso siempre ves el domingo. Utiliza diferentes `id` y lo resolverás.

Como casi siempre, todo parte del modelo conceptual de la base de datos que explota tu software. Si quieres vincular diferentes días de las semana al mismo `id`, tienes el producto cartesiano, pero entonces ya estaríamos hablando de diferentes entidades (modelo conceptual) o registros (modelo físico). Debes pensar qué almacenas en la tabla, qué identifica cada `id` de forma única. Si son días de visita, ¿por qué los identificas a todos con un `id` único siendo días diferentes? Dale una vuelta a tu modelo de datos y el programa que desarrolles empezará a tener sentido.

Para que podamos ayudarte más, amplía tu pregunta incluyendo el diagrama de tu base de datos y una descripción de lo que pretendes que haga el formulario que has desarrollado.

Si tras aclararte eso, necesitaras ayuda para modificar tu base de datos, pásanos también el dataset en SQL con unos datos de muestra con los que probar el formulario.

Comment: Perdon si me explique sobre mi pregunta, mi codigo no actualiza todos los datos, solo 1, repito quiero que mi codigo actualice todos los datos de todos los valores

Comment: Es lo que trato de explicarte, si no ha nada que los diferencie, todos tus datos son el mismo dato duplicado. De ahí que, al actualizar uno, actualices todos

Comment: Realmente solo actualiza uno!  algun consejo? De como realizarlo?

Comment: Sí, el que te he dado: diseña correctamente tu base de datos :)

Comment: No me sirve ese consejo, esta bien diseñada, gracias suerte

Comment: Pues no, no está bien diseñada porque no eres capaz de distinguir dos registros que deberían incluir algún campo que los diferenciara  para que pudieras actualizarlos por separado.

Comment: @AlandRamirezAraiza por favor, se cortes. Como te dice quien te respondio, el modelo no es correcto, y tu "error" era porque ponias un limit en el update.